# get basket product id in observer

Tags: php, magento, observers

I've set an observer for `sales_quote_add_item` in order to clear the cart whenever a certain product is going to be added (it's only supposed to be ordered alone).
I'm just not sure on how to get the product ID of the product that is about to get added. With some trial & error I've come up with this:

```
    $tmp = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem()->getData();
    echo $tmp['product_id'];
```

Which seems to be quite an ugly solution. I'm sure there is some shortcut or proper function to call for this, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is good enough

```
$productId = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem()->getProductId();
```

You may load product after if is needed

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
```

Comment: Heh, thought that I tried that - but maybe only getId(). Anyway, worked fine, and looks way better than to access the array like I did. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to get product id of quote item data

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) 
{
   $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
}
```

Hope this helps to you.

Comment: Thats for all cart Id's, right?  I'm trying to get the ID of a product that's not yet added, this observer triggers before it's added to the cart.